# How to edit the CRM dynamics email template for "Test and Enable" mailboxes?

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics-crm

Does anybody know where and how to edit/customise the subject and body of the **test and enable** mailbox emails sent by MS Dynamics CRM 2016/365 on premises?

We looked at the email template section but found nothing in there, is there anything to edit in the database directly or how else we can tweak the system so that we can have our custom test in there instead of the default "Test Message"... ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this email cannot be customized as of today. We tried but it seems to be going out of some async job outside CRM & it process the test email from respective mailbox account.

> When you run the test for outgoing email, a test email message is sent from the respective mailbox account to the email address of the mailbox.
>
> When you test the email configuration, an asynchronous job runs in the background. It may take a few minutes for the test to be completed. Microsoft Dynamics CRM tests the email configuration of all the mailboxes associated with the email server profile. For the mailboxes configured with server-side synchronization for synchronizing appointments, tasks, and contacts, it also checks to make sure they’re configured properly.

[Read more](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn832132(v=crm.7).aspx)